# Animated violin/boxplots plots with p-values for paired Wilcoxon tests

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, gganimate, ggpubr

I am trying to add p values for paired wilcox test in R. I am using the following code. The code below creates violins (density distributions) of an outcome reading (bicep) for two diets (treatment). These violins are animated over time 1, time 2, time 3. And the top of the graph prints p-values. I would like these p-values to be paired values such that

For Diet 'a' Bicep reading at time 2 is compared to time 1, and bicep reading at time 3 is compared to time 1.

And the same for Diet 'b'. So, there should be two separate p-values printed on top of the violins at time 2 and time 3. Indicating paired tests (Time 2 vs Time 1 and Time 3 vs Time 1) for both Diet 'a' and Diet 'b'.

What should be the correct code for this test? I have tried something here below based on a suggestion I got yesterday, but I ran into an error. I also think the code below just does paired tests for Time 2 vs Time 1, and Time 3 vs Time 2. Which is not what I want.

Thanks for reading.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(ggpubr)
 library(gganimate)
 library(tidyverse)
```

## Example Data

```
 structure(list(code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L), diet = c("a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), time = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), bicep = c(8L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
11L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 
10L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

## Example Code

```
example3 %>%
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(p=pairwise.wilcox.test(example3$bicep, interaction(example3$diet, example3$time), p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value,
         max=max(bicep, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_violin(aes(x=diet, y=bicep, fill=diet)) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(p, max, time), 
            aes(x=1.5, y = max+.5, label=as.character(round(p,2))),
            size=12) +
  transition_time(time) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

This is the error I get

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `p` must be length 8 (the group size) or one, not 25
In addition: There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you problem right then there is very easy solution. You got this error because of wrong syntax inside `mutate`. There is no need to call for values with `$` when you using `mutate` and pipes `%>%`:

This code gives a desired animation with minor warnings:

```
example3 %>%
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(p=pairwise.wilcox.test(bicep, interaction(diet, time), p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value,
         max=max(bicep, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_violin(aes(x=diet, y=bicep, fill=diet)) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(p, max, time), 
            aes(x=1.5, y = max+.5, label=as.character(round(p,2))),
            size=12) +
  transition_time(time) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

In case of independent p-values you just need to add `facet_wrap()`, for example. It seems to be the easiest:

```
example3 %>%
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(p = pairwise.wilcox.test(bicep, interaction(diet, time), p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value,
         max = max(bicep, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_violin(aes(x = diet, y = bicep, fill = diet)) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(p, max, time), 
            aes(x = 1, y = max+.5, label = as.character(round(p,2))),
            size = 12) +
  facet_wrap(~diet, scales = "free_x") + # add facets
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  transition_time(time) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for a solution where there would be two individual p-values for paired tests printed on top of the two violins.

Comment: Let me clarify a little more. This works but I am looking for a solution where there would be two individual p-values for paired tests printed on top of the two violins. a) paired tests for diet 'a'; Time 3 vs Time 1, and b) paired test for diet 'b' for Time 3 vs Time 1.

Comment: @DiscoR I've just updated the answer. Take a look. However, the p-value are equal for both `a` and `b`. So I can't see the point

Comment: Thanks, this somewhat solves the problem. The point for having two separate p values is that I am doing a paired wilcoxon test where means of one group at time 3 are compared to means of the *same* group at time 1. And the same for the other group. So this should result in two separate paired tests. 


Test 1: Means of Bicep at Time 1 on Diet A compared to Mean of Bicep at Time 12  on Diet A. 


Test 2: Means of Bicep at Time 1 on Diet B compared to Mean of Bicep at Time 12  on Diet B.